# How to write bigint value from Postgres to String kotlin field?

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, type-conversion

I'm using kotlin with spring data. I have a table with column "phone" which is **BIGINT** type in database, but in my @Table class this field has **String** type (`val phone: String`).
So when I try to get some records from DB using spring data repository, I get `PostgresqlBadGrammarException: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying`.
How can I fix it without changing types? I believe there must be some annotation converters or something.

I've tried to create custom query in spring data repository and cast selection result to varchar - "`SELECT phone::varchar from table...`" but it does not work.

**UPD**
I managed to configure custom converter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
class R2dbcConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun r2dbcCustomConversions(
        stringToBigIntConverter: StringToBigIntConverter,
        bigIntToStringConverter: BigIntToStringConverter
    ): R2dbcCustomConversions {
        return R2dbcCustomConversions(listOf(stringToBigIntConverter, bigIntToStringConverter))
    }
}
```

Custom converters:

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
class BigIntToStringConverter: Converter<Long, String> {
    override fun convert(source: Long): String {
        return source.toString()
    }

@Component
@WritingConverter
class StringToBigIntConverter: Converter<String, Long> {
    override fun convert(source: String): Long {
        return source.toLong()
    }
}
```

But now it tries to convert every String field to BIGINT and vice versa. How can I apply converter only for specific field in specific entity?

Comment: *... which is BIGINT type in database* It shouldn't be. That makes no sense, since phone numbers are not numbers. They are strings

Answer (score 0):

To map a PostgreSQL BIGINT column to a Kotlin String field in Spring Data without changing types, you can use a custom attribute converter. Attribute converters are used to convert database column types to Java/Kotlin types and vice versa.

Here's how you can create a custom attribute converter for your case:

1. Create a Kotlin class for your custom attribute converter. This class should implement the `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter` interface. In your case, you want to convert between `Long` (BIGINT in Kotlin) and `String`. Here's an example:

```kotlin
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
import javax.persistence.Converter

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class BigIntToStringConverter : AttributeConverter<Long, String> {

    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Long?): String? {
        return attribute?.toString()
    }

    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: String?): Long? {
        return dbData?.toLong()
    }
}
```

2. Annotate the `BigIntToStringConverter` class with `@Converter` and `autoApply = true`. This tells JPA to automatically apply this converter to all attributes of type `Long` that are mapped to `String` in your entities.
3. In your entity class, annotate the `phone` field with `@Column` to specify the column name if it's different from the attribute name. Here's an example:

```kotlin
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "your_table_name")
data class YourEntity(
    @Id
    val id: Long,

    @Column(name = "phone")
    val phone: String
)
```

With this setup, Spring Data should be able to handle the conversion between BIGINT and String automatically when you retrieve data from the database.

Make sure to replace `your_table_name` with the actual name of your table and adapt the entity class to match your specific database schema.

Comment: Seems like I don't have required `javax.persistence` library, but I've found org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter and ReadingConverter, can I use them in my case?

Comment: Yes, you can use Spring Data's `WritingConverter` and `ReadingConverter` annotations to define custom converters for your data types in Spring Data applications. While these annotations are typically used for converting data between your domain objects and database representations, they can also be used for other types of data conversion needs within your application.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I can't figure out how to apply them

Comment: `@WritingConverter
class YourWritingConverter : Converter<YourSourceType, YourTargetType> {
    override fun convert(source: YourSourceType): YourTargetType {
        // Implement your conversion logic here
    }
}

@ReadingConverter
class YourReadingConverter : Converter<YourSourceType, YourTargetType> {
    override fun convert(source: YourSourceType): YourTargetType {
        // Implement your conversion logic here
    }
}`

Comment: And they will work automatically?

Comment: No they won't work, because the error is coming from Postgres, not Spring. The smartest thing to do would be to change the column type to `TEXT` and fire the guy who thinks that phone numbers are to be stored as numbers.

Comment: this was done in order to optimize performance while searching by phone column.